# .NET 2.0 Application now running slow on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, dotnet-framework

I recently moved (and still in testing) an application from a Windows 2003 Server (Physical box) running IIS 6.x to a Windows 2008 R2 Standard (VM) IIS 7.5 server. The application is a .NET framework 2.0 application and is running under a 2.0 App Pool. This site works great except for one thing:

Takes forever to get a request back.

I've been tracking it with Chrome Inspect Element and it queries the site and can take up to 45 seconds to answer. Now when it does the page(s) render instantly but it's that initial request that's killing it.

I see no error logs or issues with the application or Windows Event Viewer or even IIS logs so not sure where to start looking next.

Some new changes was that previously the app resided behind a Pix firewall and now is behind a larger network environment in a DMZ zone (and I believe NetScaler is also being used to manage the network). I do not have rights/abilities to look at the network itself but can contact the Data center folks to look deeper into this but I wanted to make sure it's not my application that might be causing the slowdown or IIS.

In summary:

- .NET 2.0 application works great in IIS 6.x
- Application moved to an IIS 7.5 server and now slow on rendering but when it does render responds back with pages instantly.

**Edit for solution**

Found out that it was the SOAP calls that were slowing the site down. In the new datacenter my application cannot request SOAP calls and so they time out after 40-45 seconds or so. Now trying to find out if I can install a proxy server to redirect this...

Comment: is it the same 45 second wait when you try it directly on the server

Comment: Well, isolated it a little and looks like a SOAP call is slowing it down. Commented it out in the web.config and site loads fast now. No idea why that's the case...

Answer (score 1):

Solution from the OP/comment:

> Found out that it was the SOAP calls that were slowing the site down.
>   In the new datacenter my application cannot request SOAP calls and so
>   they time out after 40-45 seconds or so. Now trying to find out if I
>   can install a proxy server to redirect this...

Answer (score 0):

Commonly-hit options:

Set GeneratePublisherEvidence to false, and see if that helps.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936707

(You don't need the hotfix, just the setting)

Or:

The old server had Internet access or name resolution configured differently (wrt proxies, routing, etc), and this causes the page to wait while the call to another server is resolved and processed.